# Is it possible during run-time to modify and save an XML file inside a program and not as external file?

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, treeview

I tried to look for an answer to this question but didn't find any, maybe I didn't use the right words, but nothing came up.. maybe it's because it's not possible?

I would like to have an XML file that will be synced with a treeview, and there will be changes made to the treeview which will effect the XML file, then I need to save it, but I can't give the user direct access to this file, so I would want to compile it with the program, the question is, is it possible to modify and save the XML that way?

Thanks a lot!

Ray.

> **Additional Information (or-the final question):**
>
> Can I save an XML document in some way in my program which would be
>   available in future use even if I'll kill my program? (and NOT as an
>   user accessible XML file?) what about "resources" I know I can put an
>   XML file/doc(?) there, but will I be able to modify and keep the
>   changes I'll do to it?

Comment: Your Q is somewhat unclear. `but I can't give the user direct access to this file` why not? `I would want to compile it with the program` how, as a resource? Then it is actually part of your application and you cannot change it by your application itself.

Comment: what I meant is that the user should not have direct access to the file in a way he/she could copy it from the program's local folder.. OK, Thanks you @Sjips so is there any other way to protect the file from direct access?

Answer (score 1):

It is always possible that someone is copying a file, especially when he has admin rights. If you don't want a user to mess around with the file by editing it, you could consider encryption. Or add some kind of checksum to your XML file (not as a tag but as an XML comment so that your parser will ignore it but you still can read it and use it to check if the file is not compromised). Encryption will make a file unreadable; Checksumming will keep the readability of the file, but it will be hard to change it without detection.

Comment: This info was important for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly is an XML file? I'm almost sure you mean an XML document.

You can keep the parsed XML document in memory as an object. Then you can modify the document tree as you like. I'm not sure what you mean by "saving it" but sure you can save the object - in a binary format or as XML. The tree is not automatically serialised into a file.

I would suggest keeping your XML as an in-memory document tree and not writing it into a file until you're finished modifying it. Whether that makes sense depends on your application.

What is the reason you want to maintain a file while you're modifying the tree? Maybe you're building an XML editor?

**Edit:** One more option: save the XML in a database. You might even have an XML-type column there, depending on which DB you've got. Then it should be safe even if your program crashes.

Comment: Thanks! you've explained some important things I didn't know, so I can have an XML document 'not as a file' but as an object, that means that I will never need to write this document to a file and it will never be accessible to the user. the question now is: if as you say, I can modify the document and save it as a binary object, is that something that could last as a setting or it dies when the instance of the program dies? all I am doing is making an XML document that is synced to the treeview, the treeview should also have checkboxes and corresponding setting to each node in the XML doc.

Comment: the user is not suppose to see the XML content since there are more settings to each node which he shouldn't be able to see (business -copyrights-wise)

Comment: updated the question.. It came to me as a surprise that XML is not only a file. apparently I didn't know the right meaning of "document" and didn't work with XML before while it wasn't just reading from a file..
but it still doesn't answer my question, so I've updated it above.

Comment: Sure. an XML document can exist without ever being serialised into a file. But then again, if the XML document is huge, it's practical to divide it and store it in multiple files. "XML document" is a well-defined concept whereas the meaning of an "XML file" depends on the speaker.

Comment: Thanks Miro.. I've considered using a database in the past but for my application every tens of milliseconds matters so I wish to avoid lags. 
Now I am trying to find out if I can write to an XML document that is stored as a 'resource' in the project during run-time.
@Sjips has said that I can't change the resource by the application itself, I'd like to know what I _can_ do..